# Webgl2 instance draw using TWGL.js divisor error

Tags: webgl2, geometry-instancing, twgl.js

I'm using Twgl.js library for using webgl2

I had a array like below and I was making buffers from it with `createBufferInfoFromArrays` and use `drawObjectList` with VAO to draw it but after I changed my array for using some unsigned byte values instead of float, 
I got into trouble which chrome make this error

```
GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to draw with all attributes having non-zero divisors
```

arrays before changed:

```
EdgeArrays = {
    pos:{
        numComponents: 2,
        data: [-1,.01, -1,-.01 , 1,.01 , 1,-.01]
    },
    center: {
        numComponents: 2,
        data: new Float32Array( Lines.CenterBuffer ),
        divisor: 1,
    },
    size: {
        numComponents: 2,
        data: new Float32Array( Lines.SizeBuffer ),
        divisor: 1,
    },
    rotate: {
        numComponents: 4,
        data: new Float32Array( Lines.RotateBuffer ),
        divisor: 1,
    },
    appear: {
        numComponents: 1,
        data: new Float32Array( Lines.AppearBuffer ),
        divisor: 1,
    },
    Active: {
        numComponents: 1,
        data: new Float32Array( Lines.ActiveBuffer ),
        divisor: 1,
    },
};
```

arrays after changed

```
let Arrays = {
        Pos:{
            numComponents: 2,
            data: [-1,.01, -1,-.01 , 1,.01 , 1,-.01]
        },
        Center: {
            numComponents: 2,
            data: new Float32Array( Buffers.Center ),
            divisor: 1,
        },
        Size: {
            numComponents: 2,
            data: new Float32Array( Buffers.Size ),
            divisor: 1,
        },
        Rotate: {
            numComponents: 4,
            data: new Float32Array( Buffers.Rotate ),
            divisor: 1,
        },
        Appear: {
            numComponents: 1,
            data: new Uint8Array( Buffers.Appear ),
            type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE ,
            normalize: false,
            divisor: 1,
        },
        Active: {
            numComponents: 1,
            data: new Uint8Array( Buffers.Active ),
            type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE ,
            normalize: false,
            divisor: 1,
        },
        InstInfo:{
            numComponents: 2,
            data: new Uint8Array( Buffers.InstInfo ),
            type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE ,
            normalize: false,
            divisor: 1,
        }
    };
```

error is saying that there is no buffer without divisor but the first one (pos buffer) has no divisor!
what am I wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: @gman can anybody help me? what is the problem?

Comment: In the first one you've got `pos`, in the second `Pos`. Did you change the shader? attributes are case sensitive

Comment: oh :( I had forgot to change shaders thank you so much